# Could you link to a diagram depicting genesis of RDBMS software?

Tags: computer-science, history, relational-database, rdbms

I've once seen a picture of family relations among RDBMS software. One showing that MS SQL was derived from Sybase, PostgreSQL was derived from Ingres, etc. I need this diagram now, but can't find. Don't you know where can I find it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After 2 days of Googling and in a minute after publishing the question I've found it :-)

http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/2/22/RDBMS_timeline.svg

Answer (score 0):

[Here's a timeline](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/a/a2/RDBMS_timeline-2.svg) of the development of major RDBMS software. Also shows MS SQL deriving from Sybase, etc...

Answer (score 0):

[The first RDBMS link](http://www.mcjones.org/System_R/mrds.html) .  It was 1976.